# How would you incorporate Java into a Python Application to make an API request?

Tags: java, django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, rest

I'm building a python web app using the Django framework, but I've hit a problem. The Amazon API I want to use uses Java and doesn't support Python.
How would I do this?

I'm thinking of creating and API to send JSON data from my Python app to another API written in Java to make the request from the Amazon API and then send it back like that.
New to all this so I don't know if that would work? Seems logical to me?
How would you go about this, at the moment I've never touched Java.

Comment: I think you mean "there is a Java library for the API, but no Python library". Because APIs don't "support" programming languages, they support a higher level application protocol (such as REST), so it's perfectly possible to use the API from Python, but you'd need to write more code for it (or find a Python library for it).

Comment: Thanks Kayaman that makes more sense, still learning, just trying to learn by doing. Do you know any good websites, articles or github repo where I can learn more about doing this with Python?

Comment: Do what everyone else does, google until you either find what you're looking for, or until you can determine that such a library doesn't exist (yet). Trying to tack on a Java module without any Java experience wouldn't be easy.

Comment: You should specify which Amazon API you are trying to use and link to its documentation.